# Replace json value, and then save into new file

Tags: python, json

Yes, there are lots of example that is about this topic.... and the solution is also the same.
But i do not understand how do i assign back the replaced value back into 'data'. It seems to work for others.

I have point out the place there it should be changed below 'Json', the '111' should be update to '[7777777, 7777777, 7777777, 7777777, 7777777, 7777777 ,7777777]'.

I am guessing when i use json.dump(data, f) into new file, the 'data' here is still the same data when i load, but i thought i've already replaced? so it is fine to dump json into new file again.

```
import json
import re

p7 = ['[7777777, 7777777, 7777777, 7777777, 7777777, 7777777 ,7777777]', '[6666666, 6666666, 6666666, 6666666, 6666666, 6666666, 6666666]', '[4444444, 4444444, 4444444, 4444444, 4444444, 4444444, 4444444]', '[1111111, 1111111, 1111111, 1111111, 1111111, 1111111, 1111111]', '[2222222, 2222222, 2222222, 2222222, 2222222, 2222222, 2222222]']
p6 = ['3333333, 3333333, 3333333, 3333333, 3333333, 3333333']
p5 = ['5555555, 5555555, 5555555, 5555555, 5555555, 5555555']
p2 = ['2121211', '3434343']
# Opening JSON file

with open('Template.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

rec1 = '111'
for i in data['setting']['rule']['jsonLogic']['merge'][0]['if'][1]:
    print(i)
    i = str(i).replace(rec1, str(p7[0]))
    print(i)

with open('new_data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

Json:

```
{
    "serviceType": "Normal",
    "setting": {
        "settingName": "TEST",
        "settingDesc": "TEST",
        "settingType": "JsonLogic",
        "productIds": "uniquethings",
        "title": null,
        "description": "",
        "rule": {
            "attrs": {
                "maxResults": "10"
            },
            "jsonLogic": {
                "merge": [{
                        "if": [{
                                "and": [{
                                        ">=": [{
                                                "var": "t1"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "var": "t2"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        ">=": [{
                                                "var": "t1"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "var": "t3"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        ">=": [{
                                                "var": "t4"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "var": "t2"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        ">=": [{
                                                "var": "t4"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "var": "t3"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            [
                                111 #This should be changed to [7777777, 7777777, 7777777, 7777777, 
                                     7777777, 7777777 ,7777777] in new file
                            ],
                            {
                                "and": [{
                                        ">=": [{
                                                "var": "t1"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "var": "t4"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        ">=": [{
                                                "var": "t1"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "var": "t3"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        ">=": [{
                                                "var": "t2"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "var": "t4"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        ">=": [{
                                                "var": "t2"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "var": "t3"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            [
                                222
                            ],
                            {
                                "and": [{
                                        ">=": [{
                                                "var": "t1"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "var": "t4"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        ">=": [{
                                                "var": "t1"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "var": "t2"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        ">=": [{
                                                "var": "t3"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "var": "t4"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        ">=": [{
                                                "var": "t3"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "var": "t2"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            [
                                333
                            ],
                            {
                                "and": [{
                                        ">=": [{
                                                "var": "t4"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "var": "t1"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        ">=": [{
                                                "var": "t4"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "var": "t3"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        ">=": [{
                                                "var": "t2"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "var": "t1"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        ">=": [{
                                                "var": "t2"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "var": "t3"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            [
                                444
                            ],
                            {
                                "and": [{
                                        ">=": [{
                                                "var": "t4"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "var": "t1"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        ">=": [{
                                                "var": "t4"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "var": "t2"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        ">=": [{
                                                "var": "t3"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "var": "t1"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        ">=": [{
                                                "var": "t3"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "var": "t2"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            [
                                555
                            ],
                            [
                                666
                            ]
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "if": [{
                                ">=": [{
                                        "var": "t5"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "var": "t6"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            [
                                777
                            ],
                            [
                                888
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "customerId": 999999999
}
```

Comment: Any logic here? If not, just use `data['setting']['rule']['jsonLogic']['merge'][0]['if'][1][0] = p7[0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say ...

```py
for i in data['setting']['rule']['jsonLogic']['merge'][0]['if'][1]:
```

... `i` takes on successive *copies of* and not *refrences to* the values of  the`data['setting']['rule']['jsonLogic']['merge'][0]['if'][1]` list.

So the statement `i = str(i).replace(rec1, str(p7[0]))` just sets `i` to the replacement string but you haven't set `data['setting']['rule']['jsonLogic']['merge'][0]['if'][1][0]` to the replacement string and that's what you need to be doing. And you do not need a for loop since there is only a single element that you are replacing. So, as @Ynjxsjmh commented, all you need is:

```py
data['setting']['rule']['jsonLogic']['merge'][0]['if'][1][0] = p7[0]
```

This is because you know that `rec1` is `'111'`, `str(111)` is still `'111'` and we know that the value of `str(i)` is also `'111'`. And `str(p7[0]) == p7[0])`. So we will be replacing the entire string with just `p7[0]`. **But do you really want this to be a string or a list, as your JSON string suggests it should possibly be?**

If there can be multiple elements in the list and you needed to replace all occurrences, then one way would be:

```py
for i in range(len(data['setting']['rule']['jsonLogic']['merge'][0]['if'][1])):
    data['setting']['rule']['jsonLogic']['merge'][0]['if'][1][i] = p7[0]
```

Where variable `i` is being used to represent an *index* rather than an *element* of a list, as is generally the convention.

Comment: Great thanks on the detailed explaining, this is a very very useful case that point out my understanding error